# Error converting data type varchar to bigint SQL ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run this code it gives me an error and I don't what's wrong with this

```
DECLARE @COUNTER BIGINT
DECLARE @SQL  varchar (800)

DECLARE @SQL2 nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT @Counter =  MIN(CAST('+@cfield+' AS BIGINT)) FROM '+@ctable+' WHERE  dbo.IsInteger('+@cfield+') = 1 and '+@cdatefield+' >=''' +@ddatefrm+''' and '+@cdatefield+' <= '''+@ddateto+''''

PRINT @SQL2

-- EXEC @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL2, N'@Counter BIGINT OUTPUT', @Counter = @Counter OUTPUT

PRINT @Counter
```

Comment: Your question is mentioned unclearly. Wher you declare @fieldand what is the type?

Comment: Does the `@cfield` contain some value that can not be converted to `bigint` perhaps? Also, what do the query look like when printed with `PRINT @SQL2`?

Comment: @cfield is varchar... and ddatefrm and ddateto is varchar

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that @cfield is declared as varchar. it is contains numeric value it can be converted to bigint.But if contais character value can not be converted to bigint.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure you are not appending any numeric column with a string.

```
DECLARE @COUNTER BIGINT;
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR( 800 );
DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR( MAX ) = N'SELECT @Counter =  MIN(CAST(' 
                    + CAST(@cfield as varchar(100))+ ' AS BIGINT)) FROM ' 
                    + CAST(@ctable AS varchar(100))
                    + ' WHERE  dbo.IsInteger(' + CAST(@cfield as varchar(100)) 
                    + ') = 1 and ' + cast(@cdatefield  as varchar(100))
                    + ' >=''' + cast(@ddatefrm as varchar(100))+ ''' and ' 
                    + cast(@cdatefield  as varchar(100))
                    + ' <= ''' + cast(@ddateto as varchar(100)) + '''';
PRINT @SQL2;

-- EXEC @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql
     @SQL2,
     N'@Counter BIGINT OUTPUT',
     @Counter = @Counter OUTPUT;
PRINT @Counter;
```

For SQL Server 2012 & above you can try this.

```
DECLARE @COUNTER BIGINT
DECLARE @SQL  varchar (800)

DECLARE @SQL2 nvarchar(max) = concat(N'SELECT @Counter =  MIN(CAST('
                          ,@cfield,' AS BIGINT)) FROM ',@ctable,' WHERE  dbo.IsInteger('
                          ,@cfield+') = 1 and ',@cdatefield,' >='''
                          ,@ddatefrm,''' and '
                          ,@cdatefield,' <= ''',@ddateto,'''')

PRINT @SQL2

-- EXEC @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL2, N'@Counter BIGINT OUTPUT', @Counter = @Counter OUTPUT

PRINT @Counter
```